# how to fix killed:9 when running python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow

I am trying to clean huge amount of tweets, more than 15 million. 
SO first I collected many txt files and concat them together. 
When I try to clean the tweets by running the python file from terminal I get:

> Killed: 9

And when I run it in Jupyter notebook I get:

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

I saw some solutions suggesting to update NumPy and  tensorflow. I did and nothing happened. The same error.

I tried using only one of the dataFrames before the concat and it works fine so it seems that the problem is with the size of my DataFrame.

An example code of my cleaning process for the tweets where the error occurs:

```
    # remove mentions
   df['clean_tweet'] = np.vectorize(remove_pattern)(str(df['tweet']),"@[\w]*")
```

What can I do to fix this? I tried every possible solution I could nothing worked. 
I want to create new column that will have the clean tweets. 
I tried also just adjusting the same column but the same error.

Comment: The message "Killed: 9" seems to indicate that your program was killed by something sending the `SIGKILL` signal at it (essentially, "I'm shooting you in the face"). Or, well, more accurately, something sent the `SIGKILL` signal to the operating system on your program's behalf, essentially pointing at it and saying "hey OS, can you stop that program from doing whatever it's doing?". Based on your second error message, it might be the OS itself that does this.

Comment: If I had to guess, based on your use case, I'd say that you're overconsuming RAM or processing resources, which makes the OS very angry and it kills your program as a catch-all solution to the problem. Have you tried: (1) reading text files one by one, processing them incrementally instead of all at once? (2) Concatenating the text files manually before running the program, and in your program reading through that file gradually?

Comment: I will consider processing the files incrementally. But won't this consume more time?

Comment: Consider that you're processing the same amount of information overall, you're just not doing it all at once any more. It would only consume significantly more time if you were parallelizing the operation beforehand - but if that's the case, you could still process multiple files at once, but not enough to cause a kernel panic.